# Select closest timestamp every 30 minutes

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's assume I have following timestamp data in table:

```
Id                   Timestamp
-------------------- -----------------------
1                    2016-09-19 13:17:24.000
2576                 2016-09-19 13:47:24.000
4945                 2016-09-19 14:17:24.000
7538                 2016-09-19 14:47:24.000
10016                2016-09-19 15:17:24.000
10570                2016-09-19 15:24:51.000
11968                2016-09-19 15:47:55.000
11990                2016-09-19 15:48:08.000
13648                2016-09-19 16:18:08.000
14742                2016-09-19 16:36:55.000
```

Now I want select closest timestamp from start_date and search for next closest timestamp for found timestamp+30 min

Short example:

```
start_date = 2016-09-19 13:00:00.000
end_date = 2016-09-19 16:00:00.000
Now it should find record:
2016-09-19 13:17:24.000
Now we add 30 minutes to found date, so we will search closest timestamp for 13:47:23.000 and so on until date = 16:00.
```

Note: it should be closest approximate value, so it can be less than 30 min diff

Full Example:

```
start_date = 2016-09-19 13:00:00.000
end_date = 2016-09-19 16:00:00.000

Id                   Timestamp
-------------------- -----------------------
1                    2016-09-19 13:17:24.000
2576                 2016-09-19 13:47:24.000
4945                 2016-09-19 14:17:24.000
7538                 2016-09-19 14:47:24.000
10016                2016-09-19 15:17:24.000
11968                2016-09-19 15:47:55.000
```

How I can achieve this? I would rather avoid using cursor, it can be done by

Comment: I don't see how 11968 meets your criteria.  It is 00:30:31 minutes after the first timestamp.

Comment: 11968 is the first one >=30 mins after the previous one (10016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Id` and `Timestamp` appear in the same order use the following code (the is no recursion or CTE):

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM (VALUES
    (1,     CAST('2016-09-19 13:17:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (2576,  CAST('2016-09-19 13:47:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (4945,  CAST('2016-09-19 14:17:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (7538,  CAST('2016-09-19 14:47:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (10016, CAST('2016-09-19 15:17:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (10570, CAST('2016-09-19 15:24:51.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (11968, CAST('2016-09-19 15:47:55.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (11990, CAST('2016-09-19 15:48:08.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (13648, CAST('2016-09-19 16:18:08.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (14742, CAST('2016-09-19 16:36:55.000' AS DATETIME)))
    AS T (Id, [Timestamp])

DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-09-19 13:00:00.000',
    @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-09-19 16:00:00.000';

SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, MIN([Timestamp]) AS [Timestamp]
FROM #TempTable
WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
    CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE), -- day
    DATEPART(hour, [Timestamp]), -- hour
    DATEPART(minute, [Timestamp])/30 -- half an hour (0 or 1)
ORDER BY Id
```

If we do not have such ordering and the same `Timestamp` could appear multiple times, CTE could be used:

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-09-19 13:00:00.000',
    @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-09-19 16:00:00.000';

WITH TargetTimestamps AS
(
    SELECT MIN([Timestamp]) AS MinTimestamp
    FROM #TempTable
    WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    GROUP BY
        CAST([Timestamp] AS DATE), -- day
        DATEPART(hour, [Timestamp]), -- hour
        DATEPART(minute, [Timestamp])/30 -- half an hour (0 or 1)
)
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, MinTimestamp
FROM #TempTable
JOIN TargetTimestamps ON [Timestamp] = MinTimestamp
GROUP BY MinTimestamp -- use grouping to avoid duplicates for the same [Timestamp]
ORDER BY MinTimestamp
```

Comment: Probably I didn't specify the requirements well. Your code search for smallest timestamp for every 30 min parts, eg. it returns following values (day are the same): `13:24:00, 13:57:00, 14:00:00, 14:30:00`  but I want to find next timestamp based on previous timestamp. Thus after 13:57:00 it should search for closest (not smallest) timestamp for 13:57:00 + 30min (like 14:24 or 14:33)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query.  I'm not 100% sure what you actually need (your example seems to contract the statement).  But here is the general structure:

```
with x as (
      select min(timestamp) as first_timestamp
      from t
      where timestamp >= @start_date
     )
select t.*
from t join
     x
     on t.timestamp >= x.first_timestamp and
        t.timestamp < dateadd(minute, 30, x.first_timestamp);
```

Comment: I think he wants the first one after the start, followed by each next one that is at least 30 mins after the previously found one. Recursive CTE?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is dictated by

> next closest timestamp for found timestamp+30 min

Unfortunately CTE doesn't allow TOP(1) in recursive part. Workaround is to use row_number() ...  = 1

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM (VALUES
    (1,     CAST('2016-09-19 13:17:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (2576,  CAST('2016-09-19 13:47:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (4945,  CAST('2016-09-19 14:17:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (7538,  CAST('2016-09-19 14:47:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (10016, CAST('2016-09-19 15:17:24.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (10570, CAST('2016-09-19 15:24:51.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (11968, CAST('2016-09-19 15:47:55.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (11990, CAST('2016-09-19 15:48:08.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (13648, CAST('2016-09-19 16:18:08.000' AS DATETIME)),
    (14742, CAST('2016-09-19 16:36:55.000' AS DATETIME)))
    AS T (Id, [Timestamp])

DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-09-19 13:00:00.000',
    @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-09-19 16:00:00.000';


with found as (
    select top(1) *, r = 1
    from #TempTable
    where [Timestamp] between @StartDate and @EndDate
    order by [Timestamp]
    union all
    select t.*, r = cast(row_number() over (partition by f.r order by t.[Timestamp] ) as int)
    from found f
    join #TempTable t on t.[Timestamp] >= dateadd(minute, 30, f.[Timestamp])
        and t.[Timestamp] between @StartDate and @EndDate
        and f.r=1 
)
select *
from found
where r = 1
order by [Timestamp]
```